# H2 alias function invoked multiple times

Tags: h2

So I have created a H2 alias function to mock the results of a stored procedure.

The stored procedure has 3 declared Integer input parameters.  In my test I am registering the alias as follows.

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE ALIAS <name of my stored proc> FOR 'com.nwm.ird.irddbdao.business.repository.trade.query.H2AliasFunction.functionName'")
```

When I execute the test, the alias function is being invoked 3 times.  The first invocation all of the input parameters are null, and on the subsequent invocations it is invoking the alias with the values set correctly.

Does anyone happen to know why there are three invocations, even though the proc is only invoked once from the DAO layer?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Function as a Table
A function that returns a result set can be used like a table. However, in this case the function is called at least twice: first while parsing the statement to collect the column names (with parameters set to null where not known at compile time). And then, while executing the statement to get the data (maybe multiple times if this is a join). If the function is called just to get the column list, the URL of the connection passed to the function is jdbc:columnlist:connection. Otherwise, the URL of the connection is jdbc:default:connection.